# ERROR_MESSAGE_MAIN ERROR_MESSAGE_REASON on iPad and iPhone Safari

Tags: php, codeigniter, safari, phpexcel

My website has a functionality of downloading excel sheet. I'm using PHPExcel library with Codeigniter to create the .xlsx sheet. It works fine almost everywhere but in iPad/ iPhone Safari. The following error covers the screen.
 [Safari Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuZtR.jpg)

My code to download the file is following:

> ob_end_clean();
>
> $filename='attendance_list.xlsx';
>
> header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
>
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
>
> header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
>
> $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
>
> $objWriter->save('php://output');

And i am calling the php function with this code via jquery and AJAX. Please provide me with the answers.

Comment: do you even have an excel app or something like that on this devices ? ;)

Comment: No No.. I am using safari to download it. But it is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

use

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');