# ERROR_MESSAGE_MAIN ERROR_MESSAGE_REASON on iPad and Iphone in .Net Application

Tags: .net, excel, ipad

I am using `windows.open('url')` to download excel from c# web api. It is getting downloaded in every browsers. But for Ipad and Iphone, the file gets download but I get following error on screen

```
ERROR_MESSAGE_MAIN ERROR_MESSAGE_REASON
```

I am using the following code to return the excel data which is stored in memory stream

```
HttpResponseMessage result = null;

result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StreamContent(mem);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "myexcel.xlsx"
};
return result;
```

I have seen the same question which is in PHP. I tried checking for the same but he was giving wrong content type. Url:- 
[ERROR_MESSAGE_MAIN ERROR_MESSAGE_REASON on iPad and iPhone Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089200/error-message-main-error-message-reason-on-ipad-and-iphone-safari)

I checked for the same issue on other places and tried below code changes. I added Desktop variable so that on mobile,I can add another stream as suggested. But it doesn't work.

```
if (isDesktop)
{
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
} 
else
{
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
}
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "myexcel.xlsx"
};
return result;
```

edited - I am using ClosedXml for creating excel. 
Github link for Closed XMl issue - https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/279

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using Eppus because I couldn't find any solution for `closedXml`.